# Programmatically Examine Trust Relationships

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

Is there a way to get the trust relationship policy document using boto3? I am trying to audit the roles that allow third party access to my AWS environment.

I have been scouring the boto3 APIs to find an applicable function call, and have tried `iam.client.get_role_policy` as well as `iam.client.get_account_authorization_details`.

However, I can't quite determine what parameters to pass based on the policy information I need for a particular role, so I'm not sure those functions will return the information I'm seeking.

Essentially, for each IAM role in my account, I am trying to find the following information:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{acctID}:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "sts:ExternalId": {externalID}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I figure that if `"sts:ExternalId": {externalID}` is a part of the trust relationship, then the policy gives 3rd party access.

If there is a better way of doing this, I would love to know. I don't have much experience with IAM Roles/Policies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the [GetRole](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.get_role) API to retrieve the trust i.e. assume role policy.

Comment: Ugh, thank you. That shouldn't have been nearly as challenging as it was for me.